# the usage of "in" with meaning "concerning something"

Tags: meaning

I looked in the dictionary and noticed that **in** has the meaning of "concerning something."

http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/in_1?q=in

But I am not quite sure if I can use **in** to mean "concerning something" in any condition.

For example:

> A book concerning theology.

Could I express it this way:

> A book in theology.

Comment: "Concerning something" is a poorly worded definition.  Better might have been *with respect to*.  "Three meters in length" and "She is not lacking in courage".  We would say "A book **on** theology" or "A book **about** theology" or even "A book concerning theology".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot use **in** to describe the subject of a book.

This definition of [in](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/in) explains it better, describing this meaning as a **characteristic**. Looking at the three examples quoted in your link, courage and length can reasonably be described as characteristics: I guess you could says that richness in minerals is a characteristic.

> She was not lacking in **courage**.
>
> a country rich in **minerals**
>
> three metres in **length**

here are the examples from the cambridge dictionary:

> The new version is worse in **every respect**
>
> Are the two bags equal in **weight**?
>
> She's deaf in her left ear.

For the last one, deafness in the left ear migh be a considered a characteristic.

Answer (score 1):

As far as a branch of knowledge is concerned, the preposition is "on": *A book on theology*, or just *a theology book*.

Comment: If you are talking about a book, it is a book **on** theology, but you would get a degree **in** theology.